# Bank transfer payment not working for not logged in customers?

Tags: magento2, checkout

I am running a **Magento 2.1.12** shop and set up bank transfer payment. It works for logged in users. Not logged in users get a 302 redirect in `checkout/onepage/success/` and are being redirected to the cart, no order is placed. The logs show nothing suspicious.

Any idea where to start looking?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the log?

Comment: Yes I did, sorry for not mentioning ... I updated my post.